# How to add two derived fields in a single statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe, and based on certain condition, I need to add two calculated fields to the dataframe. I can do this in two statements, each one at a time.
Is there a way to add more than one fields at the same time?
Is there any performance difference in these two approaches?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([{"Name":"Axe","x":10,"y":20},{"Name":"Tree","x":50,"y":15},{"Name":"Sand","x":-10,"y":-15}])
df.loc[df["x"] > 0, "SUM"] = df["x"] + df["y"]
df.loc[df["x"] > 0, "DIFF"] = df["x"] - df["y"]
df.head()

    Name    x   y   SUM DIFF
0   Axe 10  20  30.0    -10.0
1   Tree    50  15  65.0    35.0
2   Sand    -10 -15 NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**numpy.c_**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) to concatenate two series along the second axis while using a list of column names in `loc` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.loc[df['x'] > 0, ['sum', 'diff']] = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[df['x'] + df['y'], df['x'] - df['y']], columns = ['sum', 'diff'])

   Name   x   y   sum  diff
0   Axe  10  20  30.0 -10.0
1  Tree  50  15  65.0  35.0
2  Sand -10 -15   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any performance advatage in using this approach or is it take same amount of time and effort?

Comment: Honestly I don't know the answer to this question. You can try on a large data set and benchmark both solutions. From my own experience I used `loc` attribute to great advantage when it comes to big data also in combination with any `numpy` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([{"Name":"Axe","x":10,"y":20, },{"Name":"Tree","x":50,"y":15},{"Name":"Sand","x":-10,"y":-15}])
start_time = time.time()
df.loc[df["x"] > 0, ["SUM", "DIFF"]] = [(df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['x'] + df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['y']),(df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['x'] - df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['y'])]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
df.head()
```

Your dataset doesn't allow to determine which approach is best so I created a dataset for testing.
This is the result:

```
sampl_x = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=30, size=1000)
sampl_y = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=30, size=1000)
df=pd.DataFrame(data={"x":sampl_x, "y":sampl_y })
```

Single line:

```
start_time = time.time()
df.loc[df["x"] > 0, ["SUM", "DIFF"]] = np.array([df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['x'] + df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['y'] , df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['x'] - df.loc[df["x"] > 0]['y']]).T
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
df.head()
```

--- 0.006986141204833984 seconds ---

Two line:

```
start_time = time.time()
df.loc[df["x"] > 0, "SUM"] = df["x"] + df["y"]
df.loc[df["x"] > 0, "DIFF"] = df["x"] - df["y"]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

--- 0.003948688507080078 seconds ---

I tried to run the test several times but the second is always more efficient.